# SSRS Count IF Multiple values

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2012

I'm creating an education report.  I have a bunch of grades and I would like to sum the number of grades A - C. Something like

```
SUM WHERE Grades IN ('A', 'B', 'C')
```

How do I do this in an expression?  Can I do a SUM on a Choose statement or something?  I tried `=SUM(Choose(1, "A", "B", "C"))` but I couldn't get it to work.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

You need to combine a `Sum` statement with an conditional statement like `IIf`:

```
=Sum(
    IIf(Fields!Grades.Value = "A"
            or Fields!Grades.Value = "B"
            or Fields!Grades.Value = "C"
        , 1
        , 0)
    )
```

This way the count is only included in the `Sum` if `Grades` is *A* or *B* or *C*.

Comment: Why doesn't this work?  =SUM(Switch(Fields!Grade.Value = "A", 1, "B", 1, "C", 1))

Comment: also I don't believe you can use OR in SSRS expressions, i'm getting red highlighted syntax...

Comment: You're only performing a comparison in the first clause of the `Switch`. You need to include `Fields!Grade.Value = ...` each time you do the comparison.

Comment: Try running it - you absolutely can use `OR`. The expression editor can be poor at parsing its own expressions. Either that or you have another syntax error in the statement.

Comment: Hi this works, you just need to put double quotes for A, B, C!

Comment: Well that's embarrassing. You are correct of course. Updated answer to prevent any confusion.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to replace 0 with Nothing. like below,

```
=Sum(
    IIf(Fields!Grades.Value = "A"
        or Fields!Grades.Value = "B"
        or Fields!Grades.Value = "C"
    ,1
    ,Nothing)
)
```

Then you should be good to go.