# SSRS Expression count records with date passed

Tags: reporting-services, expression

In SSRS I am trying to create an expression that counts all records that have been scheduled for the end of today. How can is this possible?

```
=Count(IIF(Fields!scheduledendValue.Value <= Today, 1, 0))
```

Many thanks for help

Comment: Possible duplicate of [SSRS Count IF Multiple values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24260991/ssrs-count-if-multiple-values)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your logic is good, but your formula isn't.  The "Today" function requires open and closing parentheses.  Try this:

```
=Sum(IIF(Fields!scheduledendValue.Value <= Today(), 1, 0))
```

Comment: I think you want `=SUM(...`

Comment: BJones, you're right, I saw the Today part and missed the Count part.  I'll edit the answer.  THANKS!!