# Counting values generated by a Matrix in SSRS

Tags: matrix, reporting-services, ssrs-2012

I have created a matrix report that has a Row Group of Person and a column group of  Subject with Child groups of SubmittedBy and Grading Name. The data that is being pulled through is a mixture of numerical and alphabetic data. I am needing to do a count per row of how many of a certain criteria appear. For example, I wish to count by person how many 1's they have achieved, or how many A* they have achieved (this is all grading data from a school). Is there a way to do this with matrix data?

If there is a way, can you then get a count using certain criteria, for example, if grading Name = focus count how many WB grades there are per person (row)?

[image: Design]

This is the Design

[image: Example]

This shows a subsection of data (as it is a very large dataset), but with SchoolID, Forename and Surname cut off to preserve anonymity.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [SSRS Count IF Multiple values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24260991/ssrs-count-if-multiple-values)

Comment: This answer would be correct if I wasn't using a matrix and needing to use the results of the matrix in the calculation. Unfortunately I cannot use a ReportItems! query as it is an aggregate function.

Answer (score 0):

A simple way would be to add Total to the Subject row group and use the count() function:

[[image: see attached image design and executed report]

Comment: I'm afraid this isn't possible in my design. I have now included pictures to illustrate.